# add bullet points and format using PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am new to VBA seeking help to reduce my teams effort.
Tried but couldn't achieve what i thought...hence seeking help.

Looking for 5 text paragraph out of which
1st text paragraph with blue font color and font arial
Rest four with circular bullet point and black font color.

Would be very thankful if i get any reference for this..

Regards
Rads

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a free-macro-on-demand site. Why wouldn't you just create your bullet style on a layout and use that layout for your slides? That's much faster and easier than learning VBA from scratch.

Comment: Thanks John for making me realise this is not the place what it's supposed to be earlier where you could get support when asked. Intension with this is people who are new to the system don't know ppt can create the text frame with bullet and use it accordingly. I am trying to create an in house ecosystem.. No worries as suggested will remove the question asked. Thanks for taking time to reply.